# Simulate (Mock) Large GPS Tracks

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, gps, qgis-plugins, gpsbabel

I have the following scenario:

1) I need to create GPX files for use in testing of a mobile device.

2) The tracks to be described within will span large distances over long time periods (i.e. it's not practical to just go out and record a track).

3) The people performing the testing are not very GIS knowledgeable and will struggle with things like manual file conversion, etc.

I have in mind some simple application (it could easily be a QGIS python plugin) in which you set certain parameters (time, direction & speed of track "stages") and then generate a GPX file accordingly.

But before I throw myself into something like that, does anyone know of a simpler way to do this?

I've looked into various options (creating a tour in kml and then converting into gpx, manually cut-and-paste the xml together by hand, etc.) but it all seems like a lot of hard work for what I would have thought was quite a common use case...

Answer (score 4):

If you want realistic data, then you might be able to make use of a solution that was posted over at [Are the public domain vehicle tracks available?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57881/are-the-public-domain-vehicle-tracks-available):

The OSM magicians have [released](http://blog.osmfoundation.org/2013/04/12/bulk-gpx-track-data/) a lot of GPS tracks - its ["GPX Planet"](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/gps/)

Note that there are two formats: just the points, and the GPX tracks. You presumably want GPX tracks.