# Are the public domain vehicle tracks available?

Tags: data, gpx, scenario-testing

I'm looking for recorded vehicle tracks that can be replayed to (load) test my application. Is there such data available? Best would be a european data basis but everything else would do the job as well.

Or are there (free) tools available to generate tracks that can be used to simulate a vehicle driving on a road and sending a position every 10 seconds?

Comment: If you own a Telsa S you can remotely track it using the api - Tesla Model S REST API http://docs.timdorr.apiary.io/ (base model is USD $69,900)

Comment: Part 1 is a duplicate of [Need a Benchmark GPS Trajectory data-set? Anyone?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5858/need-a-benchmark-gps-trajectory-data-set-anyone)

Comment: Part 2 of the question same as: [Simulate (Mock) GPS Tracks](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31403/simulate-mock-gps-tracks)

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap will be releasing a dump of recorded tracks in the coming weeks: watch http://blog.osmfoundation.org for more news. Note however that these will be released under the OpenStreetMap licence so unlikely to be pure public domain, insofar as there are rights associated with such tracks (which IMO is unlikely).

Comment: That sounds interesting. Will watch the blog for sure. Maybe others have alternative already available today.

Comment: It's actually just been released a few minutes ago: http://planet.openstreetmap.org/gps/ . You want the gpx-planet file, not simple-gps-points.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. The gpx file contains "only" the raw positions. Not the tracks anymore. I'm looking for something that contains more or less distinct tracks that can be used to be replayed.

Comment: You're wrong :) . The simple-gps-points files contain only the raw positions. Like I said, you want the gpx-planet file, which contains tracks. See announcement: http://blog.osmfoundation.org/2013/04/12/bulk-gpx-track-data/